# blank page in codeigniter when working with jasper

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have am trying to generate jasper report using CI.
The report when called from the controller keeps on 
showing blank page with only the query I have used in jasper ireport design page . Which is 'select * from  books'.
The function called to call the report is :getReport()

```
 public function getReport(){

    $xml =  simplexml_load_file(APPPATH .'report/report1.jrxml');
    $jasperXmlObj = new PHPJasperXML();
    $jasperXmlObj ->debugsql=true;
    $jasperXmlObj ->arrayParameter=array("parameter1"=>1); 
    $jasperXmlObj ->xml_dismantle($xml);      $jasperXmlObj->transferDBtoArray('localhost','root','','db_emergency'); 
     $jasperXmlObj ->outpage("I");   
    }
```

I expect a report in pdf format .

Comment: Look at apache/nginx errors log to see what is happening.